# Prepare json array from the result in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am looping array with for each and preparing json array as like below.

```
$resultArr = array();
$paramArr = array();
$Items = [];
$Items [] = ['value' => 17];
$Items [] = ['value' => 18];
$Items [] = ['value' => 19];
$Items [] = ['value' => 20];
$Items [] = ['value' => 21];
$Items [] = ['value' => 22];

foreach ($Items as $key => $item) {

  $paramArr['key'] = $key;
  $paramArr['value'] = $item;
  json_encode($paramArr);   
}
  $resultArr  = "Success";
  $resultArr['Parameters'] = $paramArr;
```

The above code giving me result like below.

```
   {
   "result": "Success",
    "Parameters": {
       "key": "Gentet",
       "value": "27"
    }
  }
```

But i want output to be like below.

```
   {
   "result": "Success",
    "Parameters": {
       "key": "Gentet",
       "value": "22"
    },
    "Parameters": {
       "key": "Gentet",
       "value": "21"
    }, and etc..
  }
```

What code change i need o perform to get the output like above

Comment: What you're asking for is not valid JSON.

Comment: There can not be same key in JSON, so you can not use multiple "Parameters" in the same level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push `Parameters` in loop.

```
$resultArr = array();
$paramArr = array();
$Items = [];
$Items [] = ['value' => 17];
$Items [] = ['value' => 18];
$Items [] = ['value' => 19];
$Items [] = ['value' => 20];
$Items [] = ['value' => 21];
$Items [] = ['value' => 22];
$resultArr['result']  = "Success";
foreach ($Items as $key => $item) {
  $paramArr['key'] = $key;
  $paramArr['value'] = $item;
  $resultArr['Parameters'][] = $paramArr;  // Push it here
}
```

You were pushing it after loop completes running.

Therefore, only last element was pushing into it.

Comment: @Pupli, this worked but Parameters key is showing first, i need this one to move at end

Comment: Not getting exactly what you want.

Comment: I mean Parameters value should be last, after Result in json, Right now Parameter is showing first then Result is coming

Comment: got it now? What is required?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code

```
$resultArr = array();
$paramArr = array();
$data=array():
$Items = [];
$Items [] = ['value' => 17];
$Items [] = ['value' => 18];
$Items [] = ['value' => 19];
$Items [] = ['value' => 20];
$Items [] = ['value' => 21];
$Items [] = ['value' => 22];

foreach ($Items as $key => $item) {

  $paramArr['key'] = $key;

  $paramArr['value'] = $item;

  array_push($data,$paramArr);   
}


$resultArr  = json_encode("Success","Parameters"=>$data);
```

Comment: We can do without pushing records to array as it run every time with loop unnecessarily and it will increases time complexity as well for the code.

Answer (score 1):

The Below code definately solve your problems

```
$resultArr = $paramArr = [];
$paramJson = '';
$Items = ['key1' => 17, 'key2' => 18, 'key3' => 19, 
                   'key4' => 20, 'key5' => 21, 'key6' => 22];

foreach ($Items as $key => $item) {
  $paramArr[] = ['key' => $key, 'value' => $item]   
}
if (!empty($paramArr)) {
  $resultArr['result']  = "Success";
  $paramJson = json_encode($paramArr);
} else {
  $resultArr['result']  = "Fail";
}
$resultArr['Parameters'] = $paramJson; 

print_r($resultArr);
```

It will Print result like this

```
{
  "result":"Success",
  "parameters":
[
   {
     "key":"key1",
     "value":17
   },
   {
     "key":"key2",
     "value":18
   },
   {
    "key":"key3",
    "value":19
   },
  {
    "key":"key4",
    "value":20
  },
  {
    "key":"key5",
    "value":21
  },
  {
    "key":"key6",
    "value":22
  }
]
}
```

Thanks